# Image files not displaying

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

In my XAML code I have written this:

```
<Image Source="/Images/male32.png" Visibility="Visible" />
```

and my project file structure looks like so:

[image]

But my image is just not loading?? As you can see I'm trying to add the male32.png image that I have in the Images folder in my project..

Comment: Did you set the BuildAction of the image to 'Content' ?

Answer (score 4):

Check the build action of the Image.

Example:
When you use "Build Action" of type "Content" then you access your image in this way:

```
<Image Stretch="None" Source="/images/appbar.cancel.rest.png"/>
```

When you use "Build Action" of type "Resource" then you access your image in this way:

```
<Image Source="/WP7SampleProject3;component/images/appbar.feature.email.rest.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, turns out it didn't have anything to do with the BuildAction property, all I had to do in the image path was add ".." e.g. "../Images/male32.png".

Stupid issue that's not even supposed to be an issue.

Nonetheless I have read that BuildAction could also be a potential reason ones image is not displaying. So worth checking out if you have problems with images not displaying.